# What stops Node.js from being asynchronous

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, synchronous, event-loop

When you're working with Node.js you're working with asynchronous programming.

To handle a hierachy you obviously uses callbacks. I'm also aware of some functions is blocking the main event loop, like readFileSync() for instance..

But I've noticed that something even so simple as a for loop is blocking the main event loop as well.

Example:

```
function func1() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    }
    console.log("func1")
}
function func2() {
    console.log('func2')
}

func1()
func2()
```

In this case will 'func1' allways be printed before 'func2' and first when the loop is done. This doesn't seem asynchronous to me. I mean why are we waiting for func1 to finish before running func2?

Is there any list of what actions that blocks the main event loop or can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: a computer can compute the for loop that fast, it can probably do it faster than the gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js has so-called event loop and it is executed by one thread only.

This Loop just takes task (in your case executing your .js code) and then this one-thread have to go from the beginning to the end. In this time **nothing else** will be executed.
(just note for advanced users - if you spawn workers, you can, but it is not how you usually use Node.js)

It has many advantages - no deadlocks, deterministic behaviour etc.

So the asynchronicity means that if you start aynchronous task (i.e. request to some web), it does not block your event loop to be executed. It is either put into the stack and wait when event-loop takes it, or if it is some more advanced module, it spawns worker inside to handle something inside.

However code you write will always be like:

- take task from event loop stack
- execute all the synchronous context from the beginning to the end
- put all asynchronous task to stack
- repeat the process